# Could not obtain grant code: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain - NodeJS adapter Keycloak

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, keycloak, openid-connect

I have application written in nodeJS. I'm using keycloak-connect from npm to log in using keycloak.

When I want log in app redirects me to the keycloak website, then I enter the login details, after that I got error:

*"Could not obtain grant code: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"*
post-auth.js:58

I know i can use `process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;` but it's not safe.
How i can set CA cert in nodeJS / keycloak-adapter?

post-auth.js:

```
keycloak.getGrantFromCode(request.query.code, request, response)
      .then(grant => {
        let urlParts = {
          pathname: request.path,
          query: request.query
        };

        delete urlParts.query.code;
        delete urlParts.query.auth_callback;
        delete urlParts.query.state;
        delete urlParts.query.session_state;

        let cleanUrl = URL.format(urlParts);

        request.kauth.grant = grant;
        try {
          keycloak.authenticated(request);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        response.redirect(cleanUrl);
      }).catch((err) => {
        keycloak.accessDenied(request, response, next);
        console.error('Could not obtain grant code: ' + err);
      });
```

keycloak.js:

```
Keycloak.prototype.getGrantFromCode = function (code, request, response) {
  if (this.stores.length < 2) {
    // bearer-only, cannot do this;
    throw new Error('Cannot exchange code for grant in bearer-only mode');
  }

  var sessionId = request.session.id;
    
  var self = this;
  return this.grantManager.obtainFromCode(request, code, sessionId)
    .then(function (grant) {
      self.storeGrant(grant, request, response);
      return grant;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just fix this at the environment level by configuring the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable to point to a file location containing trusted root authorities.

My blog post has some more info on this:

- [NodeJS SSL Trust Configuration](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup#nodejs)
- [Trust your own Self Signed Root Authority](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup#createcerts)

Typically you would just make this configuration change in the early stages of your deployment pipeline, such as on a developer PC. Of course it should not be made in production environments.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found simple solution: require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCA;